# Pulling post from one wordpress site to another with links to each posts

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I was trying to pull posts from one of my wordpress site to another using the WP REST API, I have successfully done that and the posts are displaying pretty well on the other site, but the issue now is that I want each post to be clickable, such that it opens the full article (post) when its been clicked on....

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://mywebsite.com/blog/wp-json/posts?filter[posts_per_page]=4');
// Convert the JSON to an array of posts
$posts = json_decode($json);
foreach ($posts as $p){
    echo '<div style="color: #fff; float: left;" class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3">';
    // Output the featured image (if there is one)
    echo $p->featured_image ? '<img src="' . $p->featured_image->guid . '">' : '';
    echo '<h5>Title: ' . $p->title . '</h5>';
   // echo '<p>Date:  ' . date('F jS', strtotime($p->date)) . '</p>';
    $summary = $p->excerpt;
    $pos=strpos($summary, ' ', 100);
    $summary = substr($summary, 0, 100);
    echo '<p>';
    echo $summary;
    echo '</p>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

So, what i need right now is to pull the link to each posts alongside....

I am just thinking of something like this: `echo '<p>Link: ' . $p->link. '</p>';`

Answer (score 0):

You should have $p->link or $p->guid available.

You should be able to do print_r($p); within foreach and see exactly what data you have- would be useful if you'd copy that response here as well as that might help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work for you :

```
<?php
    $link = get_permalink($p->ID);     // This will get the link of the post from post ID.   
    echo '<p>Link: ' . $link. '</p>';
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow this is a correct as your trying to answer but a poor answer to make it better please provide links to the resources your using in this case the wordpress docs and explain what your code is doing.

Comment: hey Thanks for the suggestion
here is the resource : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/